# Parallelizing code (attempted using multiprocessing)

Tags: parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I am new to Python and have a parallelization question.

I am filling up matrices `A` and `B` using the function `fill_mat()` as follows:

```
    for ib in range(par.nB):
       # Run function for each ib
       A[:, :, ib], B[:, :, :, :, ib] = fill_mat(ib, param1, param2, pardict)
```

where `ib`, `param1`, and `param2` are numbers and `pardict` is a dictionary. Since each of these iterations is very expensive I was wondering what is the best way for me to parallelize over `ib`?

I have tried using par `pool.apply` from `multiprocessing` but I think I am using it incorrectly because I have the function `fill_mat` print a sentence at the beginning and this is not printed all at once for all nB cases. Here is what I do:

```
print("Number of processors: ", mp.cpu_count())    
pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())    
results = [pool.apply(fill_mat, args=(ib, param1, param2, pardict)) for b in range(par.nB)]
```

Thank you for any help you are able to give.

Answer (score 0):

You've made a mistake in your iteration. You've used b, however, you should use ib. See the following example:

```
import multiprocessing

def fill_mat(ib, param1, param2, pardict):
   print(ib*ib)

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count())
results = [pool.apply(fill_mat, args=(ib, "param1", "param2", "pardict")) 
for ib in range(10)]
```

Comment: That was a typo of mine here rather than in my code. I guess then the code is correct. Odd because it's not really much faster than the non-parallelized code.